# Using STATICCALL from Solidity

Tags: solidity, evm

[`STATICCALL`](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/pull/922) provides protection against reentrancy attacks.

How can I use this functionality from within Solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be available after the 9th of October on the Byzantium network and you can only use the `STATICCALL` opcode in the inline assembly langauge.

See more info [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/214) and [here](https://medium.com/blockchannel/state-specifiers-and-staticcall-d50d5b2e4920).

Comment: It should be `STATICCALL` but the edit is less than 6 chars...